# how to add class {% render_field formset.empty_form %}

Tags: python, django

I would like my form to have their respective classes to give it a better view, at least to standardize the design

`{% render_field formset.empty_form %}`

Anyone have any ideas.
The question is that I cannot standardize everything to the same class since there is a special class for the check

[image: Here is the printscreen]

Comment: How are you rendering the other forms? That’s a form you’re passing to render_field not a field

Comment: well I have this and it works: <td>{% render_field form.tax_free class="form-check-input" %}</td>   this formset.empty_form does not work as a form?

Comment: `tax_free` is a field on a form named `form`, you pass a field, you couldn't just pass `form` to render_field. You'll need to render the fields from the empty form individually, e.g. `{% render_field formset.empty_form.tax_free %}`

Comment: Thanks for answering, I will implement it!!! :D

Answer (score 0):

Use [django-crispy-forms](https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to control the rendering behavior of your Django forms.

Comment: what happens if I'm using widget tweaks can I mix it with crispy in the same HTML template? I would like more to be able to use widget tweaks, I already used it with other forms but with this: formset.empty_form I have not found almost anything to implement it